# Running protractor tests from Gradle

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver, gradle, protractor

I'm trying to run a task in Gradle that runs protractor test files, but I can't find a way to start it just from Gradle without starting Selenium Server from a path to the machine. Right now I'm using:

```
task startSelenium {
    println "Starting Selenium..."
    ant.exec(executable: 'webdriver-manager', spawn: true) {
        arg(value: 'start')
    }
}

//run protractor
task runProtractor(type: Exec, dependsOn: ':startSeleniumServer') {
    commandLine 'protractor', 'src/test/javascript/e2e/conf.js'
}
```

But the case here is that I'm starting a local server, and using my machine configuration. Is there a way to avoid using those command calls and just start the server and run protractor file internally from project?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean the Gradle script dependent on the `protractor` and `webdriver-manager` which are installed on your machine. You hope the Gradle script can run on any machine without the dependencies of your `protractor` and `wbdriver-manager`?

Comment: Yeah exactly that!

Comment: If you have package.json, please show it.

Answer (score 1):

Includes following content in your `package.json`, if not have this file, execute `npm init` under project folder to create one.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "update-driver": "webdriver-manager update",
    "start-driver": "webdriver-manager start",
    "e2e": "protractor src/test/javascript/e2e/conf.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "protractor": "^5.3.0",
  }
}
```

Change Gradle script as following: (assume JDK and Nodejs installed on machine)

```
task npmInstall(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'npm', 'install'
}

task updateDriver(type: Exec, dependsOn: 'npmInstall') {
    commandLine 'npm', 'run update-driver'
}

task startDriver(type: Exec, dependsOn: 'updateDriver') {
    commandLine 'npm', 'run start-driver'
}

//run protractor
task runProtractor(type: Exec, dependsOn: ':startDriver') {
    commandLine 'npm', 'run e2e'
}
```

Comment: I haven't used Gradle to run my Protractor tests. Do you have any good link to get started? What are the advantages of using Gradle for the same?